# Where do you put multiple washers when you have a bolt and a threaded hole?

Tags: bolts, washer

I bought a bed second hand, and it came without instructions, the bed posts have threaded holes, for bolt to go into, and the bolts have a locking washer, and a bigger bigger, flat one. I wish to know which order they go onto the bolt, and where in relation to the holes, and the bed sides.

Comment: pictures, please .... assemble the bed post, insert the bolt and take pictures of the two ends of the bolt

Comment: i just re-read your post .... somehow i missed the part about the threaded holes .... slip the lock washer on the bolt, then slip the large washer on the bolt, then screw the bolt into place

Comment: Jstola male that an answer I was going to say the same.

Comment: Thank you @jsotola ! That helped perfectly. If you may reply that as an answer I will mark it correct and all that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slip the lock washer on the bolt, then slip the large washer on the bolt, then screw the bolt into place.

The lock washer "bites" into the bolt head and into the large washer so that the two become connected. 
The large washer has a lot of friction against the bed post, so the bolt does not turn and back out.

Comment: Also having the larger washer next to the frame spreads out the force on the frame which is usually softer and thinner than the bolt head.